# Aggregation of pandas groupby objects

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to aggregate some statistics from a groupby object on chunks of data. I have to chunk the data because there are many (18 million) rows. I want to find the number of rows in each group in each chunk, then sum them together. I can add groupby objects but when a group is not present in one term, a NaN is the result. See this case:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['A','B','C','A','B','C','B','C','D','B','C','D'],
                       'Y': range(12)})
>>> df
    X   Y
0   A   0
1   B   1
2   C   2
3   A   3
4   B   4
5   C   5
6   B   6
7   C   7
8   D   8
9   B   9
10  C  10
11  D  11
>>> df[0:6].groupby(['X']).count() + df[6:].groupby(['X']).count()
    Y
X    
A NaN
B   4
C   4
D NaN
```

But I want to see:

```
>>> df[0:6].groupby(['X']).count() + df[6:].groupby(['X']).count()
    Y
X    
A   2
B   4
C   4
D   2
```

Is there a good way to do this? Note in the real code I am looping through a chunked iterator of a million rows per groupby.

Comment: The `fill_value` is a good option, other option is to use `fillna(0)` on each groupby result and then sum them

Comment: You may want to look into Blaze. http://continuum.io/blog/blaze-expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html#pandas.DataFrame.add) and pass `fill_value=0` you could iteratively add whilst chunking I guess:

```
In [98]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['A','B','C','A','B','C','B','C','D','B','C','D'],
                       'Y': np.arange(12)})
df[0:6].groupby(['X']).count().add(df[6:].groupby(['X']).count(), fill_value=0)
Out[98]:
   Y
X   
A  2
B  4
C  4
D  2
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. I iterate through each chuck, groupby the chunk, then do groupedsum.add(newgroupedchunk, fill_value=0).