# pandas add groupby aggregations

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am reading in multiple pickle files where I do a groupy aggregation and then discard the dataframe. For example each pickle file would be a dataframe with items sold across a month. I wish to find how many unique items are sold per day.

```
n_items = []
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_pickle(file)

    # Get unique number of items per day
    df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
    n_items.append(df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='1D')).items.unique())
```

This will give me an array of groupby elements of the unique items **(note that each dataframe is across all 30 days)**.

So the final question is: How would I 'recombine' all these data frames so that I am left with just the unique items per day.

This is the closest answer I could find, but it was an added up aggregation, not using `unique()`: [Aggregation of pandas groupby objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202578/aggregation-of-pandas-groupby-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) + [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
df = pd.concat(n_items)
df = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: np.concatenate(x.values)).reset_index()
```

Another solution is create one big dataFrame from all files and then aggregate:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_pickle(file) for file in files], ignore_index=True)
df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='1D')).items.unique()
```

Comment: I'm afraid the first solution literally concatenates them and I get multiple rows for a given day. I need one final row with just the unique items.The second solution would work, except in my case the files are too large to read in.

Comment: `datetime64[ns]`

Comment: They do have times in all rows.